# Is the memory for one programme of OMNeT++ can use just 2GB?

Tags: memory, out-of-memory, omnet++

I run the simulation on a server, which has 27GB memory at least.
The function of my programme is that insert packets into the queue one by one continuely, which would be poped every time interval. The program was stopped with error, when the memory of it occupies 2GB, through observing task manager of server. So there're several questions I would to ask:

1. How to configure the value of 2GB to a larger one, while I have enough memory in server?
2. How many bytes a packet would occupied and saved in the queue, to record its informations?
3. I think for the simulator, a packet (cPacket) bring many informations, and make the memory full easily, even most of these informations would not be used. So, if I want to generate a packet, just bring the information I need, how can I do, without using cPacket?
4. I coded sizeof(queue), the value is always 4, no matter packets inserted or poped, why? Is there other words to see how much memory of a queue uses?

Other informations:
1. When I run 2 programmes parellelly, the total memory could be larger than 2GB, and there's no error if single programme use less than 2GB.

Thanks very much!!

Comment: StackOverflow's goal is to collect a repository of questions and (good) answers. Asking more than one question makes it hard to identify which is a good answer.

Comment: As a further comment, did you check if you hit any of the [memory restrictions imposed by Microsoft Windows](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366778%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)?

Comment: As Christoph said: please use only a single well formulated question on SO (i.e. please edit your question and remove question 2,3,4).

Answer (score 1):

OMNeT++ comes with a 32bit version of MinGW which means that all omnet++ simulations compiled on windows will be 32-bit processes. 32-bit processes cannot be bigger than 2GB (3GB on certain versions on windows). So what you are seeing is the hard limit on the 32-bit address space. This is true even if the main operating system is 64-bit (like in your case).

OMNeT++ on Linux and Mac OS X is using 64-bit compilers so these limitations do not apply. The short answer for the question is that you should run your simulation on Linux or Mac OS.

As this seems to be a relatively big machine, I guess you just can't reinstall it with Linux. A good workaround would be to install a 64 bit Linux distro into a Virtual box guest and use that for running your OMNeT++ simulation. That way you could use almost all of the physical resources of the machine.

Comment: Shouldn't the answer be, install MinGW-w64 and not use the one bundled with OMNeT++ ? Proposing to change OS for a library's (much less an installer's) shortcomings isn't the best solution

Comment: In theory yes. Installing MinGW-w64 would solve the issue, however I did not want to recommend something I have not tried myself. Hunting down all the packages and installing it is not always as simple as on a Linux system. Things can break at several points (like launching from the IDE, debugging). Though probably a separate Mingw64 toolchain download on omnepp.org would be a good idea.